# How to check whether code is running in background or not?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, debugging

In Java/Android, is there a way to check whether the currently executing line of code is executing on a background thread or not?

I have a lil' program I'm conjuring up that has finally reached the full-spaghetti stage... this was intentional, you see, because this way... if a competitor gets their hands on the code, and they "open the hood," after looking at it for more than 20 seconds, their hair will catch on fire and they'll run away screaming... but now even I am getting confused and I need to check for this condition somehow.

Exhibit-A:

```
// can be called from 1,067 places... some of which are background threads.
public void startDoingAFunDance(String caller, int wobbleIntensity, int spineAngle, int feetSeparationInInches) {

    if (!validCallersForFunDance.contains(caller)) { 
        Log.i("XXX", "Caller not allowed."); 
        return; 
    }

    boolean wasCalledFromBackgroundThread = // ? < what to put here > ?

    Log.i("XXX", "Was startDoingAFunDance() called from a background thread? And the answer is: " + wasCalledFromBackgroundThread);

    // classified

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to know it might be the following

```
boolean wasCalledFromBackgroundThread = (Thread.currentThread().getId() != 1);
```

background threads doesn't have id 1 (UI thread has).